# Axially symmetric metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, symmetry

Can an axially symmetric metric depend on the coordinate $\phi$?

Usually it is said that a metric that does not depend on the coordinate $\phi$ is axially symmetric since the vector $$\xi=\nabla\phi=(0,0,0,1)$$ is a Killing vector, but are there examples of  metrics which depend on $\phi$ and still have $\xi$ as a Killing vector?

Comment: What does the vector (0001) stand for? (i.e. is it $ \xi = \nabla \phi$ ?)

Comment: @Quillo it is that vector. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article [Axially symmetric spacetimes: numerical and analytical perspectives](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3106) is a very nice reference and treats axially symmetric spacetimes in generality, showing how to construct the "cylindrical" slices (see also [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.48.2635)).

If your spacetime is not only  "axially symmetric" but also "circular" (i.e. there are no meridional flows of matter), then there is a natural way to construct the coordinate $\phi$ ("circular" = there is a spacelike Killing vector field $\xi$ that has closed orbits and vanishes on a timelike worldsheet).

Such a construction is described in [these slides](https://www.ictp-saifr.org/schoolgr/Lecture2Friedman.pdf) of John Friedman. More details are given in [his book](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511977596).

A freely downloadable resource are these [extremely good lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5015): take a at look section 2.

PS: given the construction of $\phi$ as $\xi = \nabla \phi$, the metric does not depend on $\phi$ when $\phi$ is taken as coordinate.

Comment: Thanks for all the reference I will have a look to all of them!

Answer (score 2):

Spacetime doesn't come equipped with coordinates, so there is no reason to think that we automatically have anything called $\phi$ that works like an azimuthal angle, nor is there any guarantee that we *can* construct such a coordinate. This makes the problem different from the problem of defining something like the axial symmetry of a mass distribution in flat 3-space.

A coordinate-free definition of axial symmetry is the following. A spacetime S is axially symmetric if it can be written as a union $\text{S}=\cup c_{z,t}$ where each of the $c$ varies smoothly with $z$ and $t$ and is a cylinder, meaning that it's spacelike, has zero intrinsic curvature, and has the topology of a cylinder.

> are there examples of metrics which depend on  and still have  as a Killing vector?

If you want to say this in terms of Killing vectors, then you can change the description to one that says each $c$ has Killing vectors that act algebraically like those of a cylinder. That is, it has two Killing vectors, these Killing vectors commute (unlike those of a sphere), and one of them is a field with closed orbits.

Comment: *A coordinate-free definition of axial symmetry* … and then you write some statements that use coordinates?